# Could not loop thru data return from DAL Entity framework in PL

Tags: loops, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4, data-access-layer

I am using Entity Framework 4 in my project. One basic requirement is to fetch data from database using stored procedure and loop those data in presentation layer and also bind with dropdownlist, grid control etc.

I am following the flow as follow:

PL call BLL and BLL call DAL

**Sample codes :**

**DAL:**

```
namespace DAL.Repository
{
    public class CountryRepository
    {
        public static IList GetCountry(string CountryId)
        { 
            using(MyDBEntities context=new MyDBEntities())
            {
               // it calls SP in DB thru EF to fetch data
                return context.GetCountry(CountryId).ToList();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**BLL**

```
namespace BLL
{
   public class Country
    {
       public static IList GetCountry(string CountryId)
       {
           return DAL.Repository.CountryRepository.GetCountry(CountryId);
       }
    }
}
```

**PL**

```
  ddlCountry.DataTextField = "CountryName";
  ddlCountry.DataValueField = "CountryId";
  ddlCountry.DataSource= BLL.Country.GetCountry(string.Empty);
  ddlCountry.DataBind();
```

* Here binding working fine. But i am not sure is it the best option. Please suggest me.

```
       System.Collections.IEnumerator lst= BLL.Country.GetCountry(string.Empty).GetEnumerator();
        while(lst.MoveNext())
        {
            string s = ((DAL.Entity.ORM.Country)(lst.Current)).Countryname;

         /* This is the main issue. To get data from [current]
         reference of [DAL.Entity.ORM.Country] is required.
         It is strongly not good practice to keep reference
         of DAL in PL. */
        }
```

**What is best way of fetching data from database using EF with Stored procedure and using those data Independently in PL?**

**Is is safe to use static method as i have used?**

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ideally you don't want to reference your DAL in your PL. You could have a shared type with your PL and BL. The BL would convert your DAL type to this type before returning it.
2. For the example you have show yes static method should be fine.

Comment: Is there anyway to skip this conversion from DB entity to Business entity because while fetching multiple records from database, every time before sending data BAL to PL i need to convert DB entity collection to business entity collection????

Comment: If didn't separate them there your PL will need to know about the DAL. Converting types should be fairly easy using copy constructors. This can be simplified using automapper or valueinjecter. Personally I like valueinjecter since it is much simpler to use.

Comment: would you please give me an example how to write copy constructor while returning collection from DAL object to BLL object?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116.aspx - Copy Constructor and http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/ - Value Injector. For the copy constructor example show above pass the DL object instead of the same type.

Comment: Yes you are right there are number of way to convert DAL object to BAL object. But i'm worried about performance.  Suppose we are fetching >100000 record from database and converting them to BAL object will put an extra overhead.  I have following solution in my mind. Please suggest me is it acceptable?
BAL will be spilt in to following two project:
Domain.Model and
Domain.Repository OR Domain.Model.Operation
Each layer have reference of Domain.Model and will be used to transfer data from one layer to another.

Comment: @Paul that should work fine. As long as your Model is not the same as the database model you will have separated your UI from the data model. The reason this is done is to make sure your UI doesn't break due to changes in the way data is stored or retrieved.